# Magento Shipping Exception

Tags: magento

I've been trying for the last week to find a way in Magento to have some conditions for shipping. What I mean:
whenever a certain product is shipped to a certain country I want Magento to use a specific courier but I don't want it to be shown on any other products.
The problem is that we don't have one storage place, we have many in different countries. Let's take England as an example. I have a bag that is made in UK. Worldwide delivery is set to a fixed amount using UPS. But I have another deal with a local courier. And I want these products (that are made in UK) to be shipped with this courier IF they are shipped in the UK.

I tried adding an attribute to these, but I don't find an action to show this method. Also, for other products or if the address is not in England this method should not be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible do it with Magento shipping extension. You can try those free shipping extensions, or ask for trial of extensions that need pay.

I recommend use [Owebia Shipping 2](http://www.owebia.com/os2/en/) which need a lit bit 'code' to program your shipments.

and you also need add new product attribute for define where this product made. Usually this attribute select type is a drop-down list.

Assume this product attribute code is `made_from` and attribute value is `UK`. here is the simple code for condition you mentioned:

> Let's take England as an example. I have a bag that is made in UK. Worldwide delivery is set to a fixed amount using UPS. But I have another deal with a local courier. And I want these products (that are made in UK) to be shipped with this courier IF they are shipped in the UK.

here is the code for this example:

```
{
    "outsideUK": {
            "label": "UK local carrier",
            "conditions": "{shipto.country_id} == 'GB'",
             "fees": "1000"
    }
}
```

Play with this extension if you interesting. I will update more detail if I got time.